# How to get colored output with git+mintty+mingw on windows?

Tags: windows, git, mingw, mintty

I have installed the official windows git distribution, and I installed a recent mingw, and into that the mintty terminal. Then I have copied my git installation to this mingw installation, and now it works from within mintty. My only problem is that the git output is not colored. I suspect that this is because the windows git port tries to use the windows console color thingie and not the ANSI color codes which mintty would be able to interpret. Is it possible to make git use the ANSI color codes instead?

<sup>(I have tried a cygwin setup prior to this, but the performance was very, very bad, and I could not find any solution to that).</sup>

Comment: From my experience Cygwin and Mingw are about equally bad in terms of performance.  In particular, having a clean `PATH` variable helps a lot.

Answer (score 9):

from [git-config](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html):

> If this is set to **always**, git-diff(1), git-log(1), and git-show(1) will use color for all patches. If it is set to **true** or **auto**, those commands will only use color when output is to the terminal. Defaults to false.

It looks like git isn't treat **mintty** as terminal. For me using **always** instead of **true/auto** helps:

```
[color]
  status = always
```

Forcing color by adding **--color** flag to diff command work as well (with diff=true):

```
git diff --color
```

Comment: Indeed, it seems that putting `always` solves the issue. I had a working color setup with the shell shipped with msysgit (which is a standard Windows shell running `sh.exe --login -i`). Putting `always` instead of true in my `~/.gitconfig` file fix the no color problem with `mintty`. Thank you

Comment: This doesn't completely work, for example `git branch`. I also had to set branch, diff, and interactive to 'always' in addition to status.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. Config git to always show color in any ui.

```
git config --global color.ui always
```

Works for me.